# data.sql vs @Sql annotation has inconsistent behaviour in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, continuous-integration, tdd, spring-boot-test

I have noticed something very strange. Maybe it's designed to be like this.

I am running integrated tests against a local MySQL database.

I wanted to create my own data.sql file so that data could be loaded and I wanted to start with the database in the same state.

In a nutshell, it seems like the @Sql annotation runs before every test method but the data.sql file is only loaded once before all tests are ran?

I am running an integrated test for an Entity Employee that has employeeNumber as a unique column.

There are a couple of tests which try to insert the same employee twice and they should fail.

Now, this is what is happening.

If I keep an @Sql annotation over the class deleting everything before it works fine.
If I rely on the data.sql file without the annotation then the database does not clear the state and I am getting the duplicate field errors. Which means clearly the data.sql file is not clearing the state properly.

The funny thing is, those same tests that fail, if I run them individually immediately after, then they pass. So to me it is quiet obvious what is happening. data.sql is not running after every test.

Question is, is this a bug or is it normal?

Here is the code:

application.properties (inside test/resources):

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/StraightWallsTest
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root

# Get rid of JPA Hibernate's counter intuitive confusing & ridiculous underscore when no one asked for it
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
# Do not generate mappings by default
spring.jpa.hibernate.use-new-id-generator-mappings=false
# Do not print any stack trace to the client
server.error.include-stacktrace=never
# Do not generate schema
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none

spring.sql.init.mode=always
```

This is the data.sql file. I have all the delete statements on top to ensure that everything is deleted.

```
-- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 8.0.28, for macos12.2 (arm64)
--
-- Host: localhost    Database: StraightWallsLocal
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version   8.0.28

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!50503 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;

--
-- Dumping data for table `Department`
--
DELETE FROM`Employee`;
ALTER TABLE `Employee` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
DELETE FROM`Department`;
ALTER TABLE `Department` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
DELETE FROM`Role`;
ALTER TABLE `Role` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
DELETE FROM `HolidayRequest`;
ALTER TABLE `HolidayRequest` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
DELETE FROM `Period`;
ALTER TABLE `Period` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;


LOCK TABLES `Department` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `Department` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `Department` VALUES (1,'Engineering'),(2,'Plumbing'),(3,'Roofing'),(4,'Carpentry'),(5,'Bricklaying'),(6,'Office');
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `Department` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;

--
-- Dumping data for table `Employee`
--

LOCK TABLES `Employee` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `Employee` DISABLE KEYS */;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `Employee` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;

--
-- Dumping data for table `HolidayRequest`
--

LOCK TABLES `HolidayRequest` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `HolidayRequest` DISABLE KEYS */;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `HolidayRequest` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;

--
-- Dumping data for table `Period`
--

LOCK TABLES `Period` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `Period` DISABLE KEYS */;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `Period` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;

--
-- Dumping data for table `Role`
--

LOCK TABLES `Role` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `Role` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `Role` VALUES (1,'Deputy Head'),(2,'Head'),(3,'Manager'),(4,'Senior Employee'),(5,'Junior Employee');
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `Role` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE=@OLD_TIME_ZONE */;

/*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE */;
/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS */;
/*!40014 SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40111 SET SQL_NOTES=@OLD_SQL_NOTES */;

-- Dump completed on 2022-04-20 23:35:41
```

The test cases:

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@Sql(statements = {"DELETE FROM Employee; ALTER TABLE Employee AUTO_INCREMENT=1"})
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
@IfProfileValue(name = "spring.profiles.active", value = "test")
public class EmployeeAccountApiIntegratedTest {

    @LocalServerPort
    private int port;

    @Autowired
    private TestRestTemplate rest;

    @Test
    @DisplayName("My First integrated test with Test rest template, seems to be easier than i thought")
    public void whenPostingToDbEverythingWorksAndRealDbDoesNotHit(){

        RegistrationRequest registrationRequest = new RegistrationRequest();
        registrationRequest.setFirstName("Crow");
        registrationRequest.setLastName("Ice");
        registrationRequest.setEmployeeNumber("38476");
        registrationRequest.setPassword("abcdef");
        registrationRequest.setTermsAccepted(true);

        HttpEntity<RegistrationRequest> request = new HttpEntity<RegistrationRequest>(registrationRequest);

        ResponseEntity<String> response = rest.postForEntity(
                "/register",
                request,
                String.class
        );

        assertEquals(HttpStatus.CREATED, response.getStatusCode());
    }


    @Test
    @DisplayName("given employee doesnt exist, when authentication request is made, it should return forbidden even with valid credentials")
    public void shouldReturnForbiddenBecauseEmployeeDoesntExist(){
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.set("Content-Type", "application/json");
        headers.set("Accept", "text/plain");

        LoginRequest loginRequestBody = new LoginRequest();
        loginRequestBody.setEmployeeNumber("abcde");
        loginRequestBody.setPassword("abcde");

        HttpEntity<LoginRequest> loginRequest = new HttpEntity<LoginRequest>(loginRequestBody, headers);


        ResponseEntity<String> loginResponse = rest.postForEntity(
                "/login",
                loginRequestBody,
                String.class
        );

        assertEquals(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN, loginResponse.getStatusCode());
    }

    @Test
    @DisplayName("Given employee exists and valid credentials, when authentication is requested, then it should return status ok/200")
    public void returnsOkayWhenEverythingIsValid(){
        HttpHeaders registerHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        registerHeaders.set("Content-Type", "application/json");
        registerHeaders.set("Accept", "application/json");

        RegistrationRequest registrationRequest = new RegistrationRequest();
        registrationRequest.setFirstName("Crow");
        registrationRequest.setLastName("Ice");
        registrationRequest.setEmployeeNumber("mnopq");
        registrationRequest.setPassword("abcdef");
        registrationRequest.setTermsAccepted(true);

        HttpEntity<RegistrationRequest> request = new HttpEntity<RegistrationRequest>(registrationRequest, registerHeaders);

        ResponseEntity<String> registrationResponse = rest.postForEntity(
                "/register",
                request,
                String.class
        );

        assertEquals(HttpStatus.CREATED, registrationResponse.getStatusCode());

        HttpHeaders loginHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        loginHeaders.set("Content-Type", "application/json");

        LoginRequest loginRequestBody = new LoginRequest();
        loginRequestBody.setEmployeeNumber(registrationRequest.getEmployeeNumber());
        loginRequestBody.setPassword(registrationRequest.getPassword());

        HttpEntity<LoginRequest> loginRequest = new HttpEntity<LoginRequest>(loginRequestBody, loginHeaders);

        ResponseEntity<String> loginResponse = rest.postForEntity(
                "/login",
                loginRequestBody,
                String.class
        );

        assertEquals(HttpStatus.OK, loginResponse.getStatusCode());
    }

    @Test
    @DisplayName("Given valid employee number but invalid password, when authentication is requested, then the employee should be forbidden")
    public void returnsForbiddenWhenEmployeeNumberIsInValid(){
        HttpHeaders registerHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        registerHeaders.set("Content-Type", "application/json");
        registerHeaders.set("Accept", "application/json");

        RegistrationRequest registrationRequest = new RegistrationRequest();
        registrationRequest.setFirstName("Crow");
        registrationRequest.setLastName("Ice");
        registrationRequest.setEmployeeNumber("gh78q");
        registrationRequest.setPassword("abcdef");
        registrationRequest.setTermsAccepted(true);

        HttpEntity<RegistrationRequest> request = new HttpEntity<RegistrationRequest>(registrationRequest, registerHeaders);

        ResponseEntity<String> registrationResponse = rest.postForEntity(
                "/register",
                request,
                String.class
        );

        assertEquals(HttpStatus.CREATED, registrationResponse.getStatusCode());

        HttpHeaders loginHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        loginHeaders.set("Content-Type", "application/json");

        LoginRequest loginRequestBody = new LoginRequest();
        loginRequestBody.setEmployeeNumber("kdjfi");
        loginRequestBody.setPassword(registrationRequest.getPassword());

        HttpEntity<LoginRequest> loginRequest = new HttpEntity<LoginRequest>(loginRequestBody, loginHeaders);

        ResponseEntity<String> loginResponse = rest.postForEntity(
                "/login",
                loginRequestBody,
                String.class
        );

        assertEquals(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN, loginResponse.getStatusCode());
    }

    @Test
    @DisplayName("Given an employee already exists, when an attempt is made to register with the same employee number, then an exception should be thrown")
    public void noDuplicateEmployeeNumber(){
        HttpHeaders registerHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        registerHeaders.set("Content-Type", "application/json");
        registerHeaders.set("Accept", "application/json");

        RegistrationRequest registrationRequest = new RegistrationRequest();
        registrationRequest.setFirstName("Crow");
        registrationRequest.setLastName("Ice");
        registrationRequest.setEmployeeNumber("gh78q");
        registrationRequest.setPassword("abcdef");
        registrationRequest.setTermsAccepted(true);

        HttpEntity<RegistrationRequest> request = new HttpEntity<RegistrationRequest>(registrationRequest, registerHeaders);

        ResponseEntity<String> registrationResponse = rest.postForEntity(
                "/register",
                request,
                String.class
        );

        assertEquals(HttpStatus.CREATED, registrationResponse.getStatusCode());


        HttpHeaders registerHeaders2 = new HttpHeaders();
        registerHeaders2.set("Content-Type", "application/json");
        registerHeaders2.set("Accept", "application/json");

        RegistrationRequest registrationRequest2 = new RegistrationRequest();
        registrationRequest2.setFirstName("Crow");
        registrationRequest2.setLastName("Ice");
        registrationRequest2.setEmployeeNumber("gh78q");
        registrationRequest2.setPassword("abcdef");
        registrationRequest2.setTermsAccepted(true);

        HttpEntity<RegistrationRequest> request2 = new HttpEntity<RegistrationRequest>(registrationRequest, registerHeaders);

        ResponseEntity<String> registrationResponse2 = rest.postForEntity(
                "/register",
                request,
                String.class
        );

        assertEquals(HttpStatus.CONFLICT, registrationResponse2.getStatusCode());

    }

    /**
     * Ideally this should be throwing a 409, But there isnt enough info about this, so leaving it as a genetic error
     */
    @Test
    @DisplayName("Given integrity constraint violation, when employee tries to register, then throw an exception")
    public void returnsHttpConflict(){
        HttpHeaders registerHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        registerHeaders.set("Content-Type", "application/json");
        registerHeaders.set("Accept", "application/json");

        RegistrationRequest registrationRequest = new RegistrationRequest();
        registrationRequest.setFirstName("Crow");
        registrationRequest.setLastName("Ice");
        registrationRequest.setEmployeeNumber("gh78q");
        registrationRequest.setPassword("abcdef");
        registrationRequest.setTermsAccepted(true);

        HttpEntity<RegistrationRequest> request = new HttpEntity<RegistrationRequest>(registrationRequest, registerHeaders);

        ResponseEntity<String> registrationResponse = rest.postForEntity(
                "/register",
                request,
                String.class
        );

        assertEquals(HttpStatus.CREATED, registrationResponse.getStatusCode());

        ResponseEntity<String> registrationResponse2 = rest.postForEntity(
                "/register",
                request,
                String.class
        );

        assertEquals(HttpStatus.CONFLICT, registrationResponse2.getStatusCode());

    }





}
```

Just to reiterate what is happening.

If I keep this annotation: Everything works perfectly

```
@Sql(statements = {"DELETE FROM Employee; ALTER TABLE Employee AUTO_INCREMENT=1"})
```

If I delete that annotation, then run all the tests in the class I get the duplicate errors for few methods that maybe be using the same employee number.

[image: All tests pass initially]

Here is what is confusing. When I comment out the @Sql annotation like so:
Two of the tests fail

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
//@Sql(statements = {"DELETE FROM Employee; ALTER TABLE Employee AUTO_INCREMENT=1"})
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
@IfProfileValue(name = "spring.profiles.active", value = "test")
public class EmployeeAccountApiIntegratedTest {
```

[image: Two of the tests fail because of duplicates, the state wasn't cleared for each method]

[image: Error message:]

[image]

Funny thing is if I go to that same test that failed and run that test method in isolation it works:

[image: Test works when tested individually]

So the main question is, is this normal, is it supposed to be like this? Or is it a bug?
If it is the former, then it should be properly documented.
It's not intuitive and not great architecture IMHO

Any advice would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@Sql` annotation has the execution phase:

```
Sql.ExecutionPhase executionPhase() default Sql.ExecutionPhase.BEFORE_TEST_METHOD;

public static enum ExecutionPhase {
    BEFORE_TEST_METHOD,
    AFTER_TEST_METHOD;

    private ExecutionPhase() {
    }
}
```

As you can see the default value is `BEFORE_TEST_METHOD`. Hence SQL within this annotation will be run before every test. When you commented it out, your delete statements will not be executed as you noticed, and you have conflicts/collisions between the particular tests. This is normal, no SQL annotation, and no SQL statements will be executed.

Now `data.sql` file. From [docs.spring.io](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto.data-initialization.using-basic-sql-scripts):

> Script-based DataSource initialization is performed, by default, before any JPA EntityManagerFactory beans are created. schema.sql can be used to create the schema for JPA-managed entities and data.sql can be used to populate it.

EntityManagerFactory is not created for every test, but rather for every data source. Hence `data.sql` is executed only once somewhat similar to `@BefereClass` or `@BeforeAll`. It is not a bug, it is expected behaviour, however, I agree not very well documented.

Comment: Thank you for this. Just one question. What if I wanted to have a separate data.sql file for test resources and main resources, is this possible? How could I load a separate resource file for tests?

Comment: Just put ```data.sql``` in the ```src/test/resources``` directory